# Как соединить две точки и чтобы, когда я перемещал точку она следовала за ней

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image: Вот это]

Как показано на изображение у нас есть две точки

1: фиолетовая

2: белая.

Как их соединить кривой? Просто сделать через path, и написать координаты этих точек не получится, потому что блоки можно перетаскивать(drag $ drop), а из этого этот вариант сразу отпадает.
Проект сделан в React

Comment: ну если есть функция, в которой меняется useState({x: 10, y: 10}) координаты ведущего блока, то посчитать насколько меняются координаты x, y, и эту разницу прибавить к координатам последователя его useState.

Answer (score 1):

Вон целая [статья](https://dragonman225.js.org/curved-arrows.html) есть об этом.